# Unable to run a join of large tables in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I am having a difficulty joining two large tables (>30GB each) in oracle 11g
I receive an error ORA-01652 : unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace DBXTEMP.

I tried to fetch the first 10,000 joined lines, it worked but with oracle 11g which we still use in the team, it doesn't allow to run OFFSET as it is a feature of oracle12+. Rownum method doesn't work as well.

Is there an idea how i can join the 2 large tables without facing this error?

Comment: This question is about database administration and should be asked at https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

As the error is telling you, you need to add more space to your temp tablespace DBXTEMP if you want to do operations on those big tables.

Comment: Hello, In case of a join of three large tables say >100 GB each, how much size should i add to the temp tablespace?

Comment: @jonas - That depends on the query and query plan and what is taking all your TEMP space.  There is no general guideline.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you have insufficient TEMP space. If you want root cause, you need to see where the temp space usage is coming from. It could be from a (hash) join, or it could be a sort. A SQL Monitor report will determine that for you. Then you might be able to address the problem.

Of course, you could simply just add some TEMP space and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you originally asked: "*I am having a difficulty importing data from a large database in oracle 11g, into Couchbase.*"

Three solutions come to mind

1. you can use rowid but you need to propagate it up as a selected field from a sub-select

   ```
    select t.*, mod(rn,5) as num from (select t.*, rownnum rn
      from t
     ) t;
   ```

   Then just add a where clause like "mod(rn,5) = 0" and run through five times.
   Alternitively alpply limits and offsets.
2. Load the individual unjoined tables into Couchbase and then you can use N1QL to join them.
3. Load the individual unjoined tables into Couchbase and then you can use the Eventing Service to quickly join them in toyour final document form.

Solution three (3) can work without Indexes and it can clean up as it goes (delete the rows [now docs] form the "tables" you are joining) so no extra space would be needed.  If you want to pursue the Eventing Function solution just reach out to me in a DM.

Best

Jon Strabala
Principal Product Manager - Server‌
Couchbase, Inc.